# How to create a Salesforce Case with attachments using REST API?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-rest-api

I was able to create a new Case using the REST API but i need some help regarding these.

1. How to create cases in bulk ?
2. Can we create cases with attachments(CSV) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create case with attachments.
we need to use two different APIs

1. First we need to create case using this api

*/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Case*

After Creating case it will return Case Id

2. Second we need to use ContentVersion API

*/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/ContentVersion*

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm

Convert File to Base64

```
payload = json.dumps({
    'Title': 'file.csv',
    'PathOnClient': 'Simple',
    'ContentLocation': 'S',
    'FirstPublishLocationId': caseid,
    'VersionData': Base64
  })
```